# List Phoenix API

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I would like to have an endpoint `/api/api_endpoints/` that list all the public api endpoints. Similar to `mix phx.routes`, but I only want to list things like

```
...
GET /api/users
PUT /api/users/name
...
```

Things like that. I looked in the documentation but did not see anything for listing routes.

Comment: There is nothing currently built into Phoenix to do that. However, you could use a library like [phoenix_swagger](https://hex.pm/packages/phoenix_swagger) to accomplish something similar.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look as I have just started to use swagger for the same project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing built in, but for something as simple as you want you could always roll your own. All the routes are stored inside your router as a list of `Phoenix.Router.Route` stucts. For example in a project called `Residential`:

```
iex(1)> ResidentialWeb.Router.__routes__
[%Phoenix.Router.Route{assigns: %{}, helper: "page", host: nil, kind: :match,
opts: :index, path: "/", pipe_through: [:browser],
plug: ResidentialWeb.PageController, private: %{}, verb: :get},
%Phoenix.Router.Route{assigns: %{}, helper: "user", host: nil, kind: :match,
opts: :index, path: "/users", pipe_through: [:browser],
plug: ResidentialWeb.UserController, private: %{}, verb: :get},
%Phoenix.Router.Route{assigns: %{}, helper: "user", host: nil, kind: :match,
opts: :edit, path: "/users/:id/edit", pipe_through: [:browser],
plug: ResidentialWeb.UserController, private: %{}, verb: :get},
```

You can map over them and extract the `verb` and `path` and show them as you please.

This is pretty much how `mix phx.routes` works, if you [take a look at the implementation](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/lib/mix/tasks/phx.routes.ex)

Comment: Also note that the `__routes__` function is an internal API, so it can be changed or removed without notice.

Comment: @JustinWood, do you have any suggestions for an non-internal API? Looking at the __routes__ it looks like that is what `mix phx.routes` use to generate its output.

Comment: Also, `Phoenix.Router.ConsoleFormatter.format/1` can be used to generate the same string output as `$mix phx.routes`. While it is accessing an internal API I will mark this as an answer. Thx @mario.